# How to read data from a specific column in python?

Tags: python

I have data as below , I want to read only a specific column and compare it with some standard values , kindly assist.

```
/dev/sda2             4.9G  1.5G  3.2G  32% /
/dev/sda9             3.9G   46M  3.7G   2% /
/dev/sda7              20G  8.1G   11G  45% /
/dev/sda6              81G   31G   46G  41% /
/dev/sda3              49G  128M   46G   1% /
/dev/sdb2             224G  135G   78G  64% /
/dev/sda5              49G  2.5G   44G   6% 
/dev/sda8              20G  5.7G   13G  31%
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: specify how are you trying to access the data, how it is stored, what error/problem you faced with your code and your desired result.

Comment: I'm reading a .txt file , storing the content of it in variable.Then i check for a specific word in a text file and print it , below code:-

Comment: cndc_p1=open("new.txt","r"),l1=cndc_p1.readlines() ,                              
    for line_1 in l1:
 if "/dev/" in line_1:
  print(line_1)                                                                                     I'm getting output as above , however after checking this condition i need to read only "%" value